# How to aggregate in Kibana information from multiple Elasticsearch indexes?

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

We are setting up logs from several related applications so the log events are imported into Elasticsearch (via Logstash). It was straightforward create Kibana dashboards to visualize log indexes for each application, but since the applications are related and its activities belong to the same pipeline, it would be great to build a dashboard that would show aggregated information, collected from different applications. Such dashboard would be especially useful to track failures and performance problems.

Right now I can see three main ways to implement aggregated dashboard:

1. Keep separate application logs and configure Kibana dashboard that would consume information from different applications. I am afraid this can be a challenging task, I am not even sure Kibana fully supports it.
2. Revise application logging so they will all log to the same index. What I dislike about this is that log event structure must be then unified across applications, and they are built by different people in different languages. I've lost my faith to centralized control over such low level details like logging.
3. Keep applications log and corresponding Elastichsearch indexes as they are now, but set up a new index which will contain aggregate information. [This article](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/logging-elasticsearch-events-with-logstash-and-elasticsearch/) describes how to configure Elasticsearch to dump it’s logs to Logstash which would then insert them back into Elasticsearch for searching. At first glance this approach may look surprising: why would you need to re-insert log data once again into the same database? It's another index, it adds overhead, uses more space etc. But it gives the opportunity to set up the index in a way that will be suitable for a aggregated Kibana dashboard.

I wonder if someone has gone through a similar dilemma and can share their experience.

Comment: I haven't tried this and I don't know if it would work, so take it for what it's worth... you could try setting up an alias that points to the different indexes you want to view as a single index and then tell kibana to use that as your index.

Comment: @Alcanzar, thanks for the tip. That's interesting, I'll look into it although I suspect we will need to reshape data being aggregated.

Comment: Just a thought, could you ingest everything in the same index and then use tags to query for separate dashboards and don't use tag for aggregate?

Comment: Isn't this what a tribe is for?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can just set the Default Index to `_all` if you're not planning to use timestamped indices.

Using menus, go to Configure, click the Index tab, and set Timestamping to "none" and Default Index to `_all`.  The JSON schema would end up containing something like this:

```
  "index": {
    "interval": "none",
    "pattern": "[logstash-]YYYY.MM.DD",
    "default": "_all",
    "warm_fields": false
  },
```

If you need timestamped indices, you would need to choose the approriate interval and enter a comma-separated list of the indices, each specified in the proper format.

Comment: Yes, then I can aggregate data from all indexes. But the problem is that indexes generated by different applications will refer certain things in different way, so I will have to either have common conventions for all applications or build another index from those. I am trying to figure out what's best.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I would go with setting up conventions going forward, rather than porting things to a new index.

Answer (score 1):

We faced the same problem, but in different perspective.

I needed to get data from 2 indices in Kibana. Our data structure is the same in both indices.

So, I added second index manually (section Settings->Objects):

```
{
  "index": [
    "index_one",
    "index_two"
  ],
 ...
}
```

It helped me to get data from those indices that I need.